# how to update record while using from clause query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I wrote that code in from clause query

```
select empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno, grade gr 
from emp left outer join salgrade on ( emp.sal between losal and hisal)
```

I can not update or delete the data from the cell grade. What to do?

Comment: i can not update or delete the data from the cell grade what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing a block on a FROM clause query is OK if you want to use that block for **selecting** data from the database, but is a bad choice if you want to perform DML (insert, update, delete) as Forms can't do that.

An alternative would be to:

- create a view (which utilizes the same SELECT statement you wrote)
- create an INSTEAD OF trigger which would deal with inserts, updates and deletes
- base a form data block on that view